# how to pass a condition as parameter to function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, function-parameter

I have created an array of function pointers to swap two variables.
pointer pointing to these functions namely: swap1, swap2. swap3 and swap4.
swap2 is swaping using pointer passed as arguments.
but while declaring the function pointer, only int and int are passed as arguments. after compiling this causes many warnings.
so do we have a better way of passing the argument, where we put condition in function call itself. 
code is given below.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int swap1(int ,int );
    int swap2(int* ,int* );
    int swap3(int ,int );
    int swap4(int, int);

    int swap1(int a,int b)
    {
      int temp=a;
      a=b;
      b=temp;

      printf("swapped with 3rd variable :%d, %d\n", a,b);
    }
    int swap2(int *a,int *b)
    {
      int temp = *a;
      *a = *b;
      *b = temp;
      printf("swapped with pointer :%d, %d\n", *a,*b);
    }

    int swap3(int a,int b)
    {
      a+=b;
      b=a-b;
      a-=b;
      printf("swapped with 2 variable :%d, %d\n", a,b);
    }
    int swap4(int a,int b)
    {
      a=a^b;
      b=a^b;
      a=a^b;
      printf("swapped with bitwise operation :%d, %d\n", a,b);
    }
    int main()
    {
      int ch;
      int a=3;
      int b=4;
      printf("enter the option from 0 to 3\n");
      scanf("%d",&ch);
      int (*swap[4])(int, int) ={swap1,swap2,swap3,swap4};// function pointer

/*can we pass something like int(*swap[4]( condition statement for 'pointer to variable' or 'variable')*/

       if (ch==1)// at '1' location, swap2 is called.
          {
           (*swap[ch])(&a,&b);//passing the addresses
           }
      else 
         {
         (*swap[ch])(a,b);
         }
      return 0;
    }
```

some warnings are as follows.

```
                 at line 36 in file '9e748221\script.c'
        WARNING: found pointer to int where int is expected
                 at line 47 in file '9e748221\script.c'
        WARNING: found pointer to int where int is expected
                 at line 47 in file '9e748221\script.c'
```

Comment: C is **strictly** pass-by-value; all your functions don't work, except for `swap2`. And `swap3` invokes undefined behaviour on signed integer over/underflow. Not clear what you are trying to accomplish, if you want to test different functions, just call them. The error messages are very clear.

Comment: Well, if you want to use function pointers, all your functions should take the same arguments. So you can't just have one function which takes `int*, int*`, whereas the others take `int, int`. Either all your functions should takes `int*, int*` or all should take `int, int`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: That is **very bad advice**

Comment: Your functions should be returning int's. They are not !

Comment: @Olaf I re-thunk it and deleted it right after I typed it....

Comment: Sorry to say, but your code has almost as many things wrong as it has lines. If you are learning C by trial&error: **don't!** Work through a good C book.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: Your edit does not make it any better.

Comment: `swap2` is the correct swap function btw. Forget about the others. In fact, `swap3` has an overflow bug.

Comment: @Olaf all the functions are working.
please do suggest book. Thanks. :)

Comment: **They are not! Check the values in the caller!** Re the book: I don't use a C book, but the standard. For a begin ner's book, you should search yourself. There is a list on stack overflow, though.

Comment: @AnthonyD.thanks. but what if I am not using function pointer, in that case is it possible to pass a condition as parameter to function? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes.  There are a number of problems with your code, but I'll focus on the ones to which the warnings you presented pertain.  You declare `swap` as an array of four pointers to functions that accept two `int` arguments and return an `int`:

> ```
> int (*swap[4])(int, int)
> ```

Your function `swap2()` is not such a function, so a pointer to it is not of the correct type to be a member of the array.  Your compiler might do you a better favor by rejecting the code altogether instead of merely emitting warnings.

Having entered a pointer to `swap2()` into the array anyway, over the compiler's warnings, how do you suppose the program could call that  function correctly via the pointer?  The type of the pointer requires function arguments to be `int`s; your compiler again performs the dubious service of accepting your code with only warnings instead of rejecting it.

Since the arguments in fact provided are the correct type, it might actually *work* on systems and under conditions where the representations of `int` and `int *` are compatible.  That is no excuse, however, for writing such code.

Because pointers and `int`s are unchanged by the default argument promotions, one alternative would be to omit the prototype from your array declaration:

```
int (*swap[4])() = {swap1,swap2,swap3,swap4};
```

That says that each pointer points to a function that returns `int` and accepts a fixed but unspecified number of arguments of unspecified types.  At the point of the call, the actual arguments will be subject to the default argument promotions, but that is not a problem in this case.  This option does prevent the compiler from performing type checking on the arguments, but in fact you cannot do this correctly otherwise.

Your compiler might still warn about this, or could be induced to warn about it with the right options, but the resulting code nevertheless conforms and does the right thing, in the sense that it calls the pointed-to functions with the correct arguments.

Comment: "a function that returns int and accepts a fixed but unspecified number of arguments " --> I'd thought a non-fixed or `...` function would be OK too as with `int (*swap)() = printf;` but apparently that is a "initialization from incompatible pointer type" problem.  LSNED

Comment: @JeremyP, if the requirement is to store function pointers in an array, accommodating functions with inhomogeneous argument lists as the OP describes, then that's the *only* conforming idea available.  You can certainly question the wisdom of choosing such a design in the first place, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In this case, as it turns out the requirement doesn't actually exist. All the functions should take `int*`

Comment: @JeremyP, the OP's specific provision for calling each function with the appropriate arguments suggests that the OP thinks the requirement *does* exist.  The question is about how to implement it.  Whether that design is appropriate for the task the program is intended to solve is a separate matter.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you can either go further than the OP's original question, or you can wait for him to ask the inevitable "why are my values not swapped in the caller?" on Stack Overflow. I'd go for the former, especially as the strict answer to his question is pretty bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the warnings first: You declare an array of functions which take `int` parameters. This means that `swap2` is incompatible with the type of element for the array you put it in. This will generate a diagnostic.

Furthermore, when you call one of the functions in the array, the same array declaration tells the compiler that the parameters need to be `int`s not pointers to `int`. You get two diagnostics here, one for each parameter.

To fix the above all your functions need to have compatible prototypes with the element type of the array. Should it be `int` or `int*`? This brings us to the other problem.

C function arguments are always pass by value. This means that the argument is copied from the variable onto the stack (or into the argument register depending on the calling convention and argument count - for the rest of this post, I'll assume arguments are placed on the stack for simplicity's sake). If it's a literal, the literal value is put on the stack. If the values on the stack are changed by the callee **no attempt is made by the caller, after the function returns, to put the new values back in the variables**. The arguments are simply thrown away.

Therefore, in C, if you want to do the equivalent of call by reference, you need to pass pointers to the variables you use as arguments as per `swap2`. All your functions and the array should therefore use `int*`. Obviously, that makes one of `swap1` and `swap2` redundant.

The correct array definition is

```
int (*swap[4])(int*, int*) = {swap1, swap2, swap3, swap4};
```

and the definition of each function should be modified to take `int*` parameters. I'd resist the temptation to use `int (*swap[4])()` simply because it circumvents type safety. You could easily forget the `&` in front of an int argument when the called function is expecting a pointer which could be disastrous - the best case scenario when you do that is a seg fault.

Answer (score 1):

The others have done great work explaining what the problems are. *You should definitely read them first.*

I wanted to actually show you a working solution for that sort of problem.

Consider the following (working) simple program :

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>

void swap1(int* aPtr, int* bPtr) {
    printf("swap1 has been called.\n");
    int tmp = *aPtr;
      *aPtr = *bPtr;
      *bPtr = tmp;
}

void swap2(int* aPtr, int* bPtr) {
    printf("swap2 has been called.\n");
    *aPtr += *bPtr;
    *bPtr  = *aPtr - *bPtr;
    *aPtr -= *bPtr;
}


int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    printf("a is now %d, and b is %d\n\n", a, b);

    // Declare and set the function table
    void (*swapTbl[2])(int*, int*) = {&swap1, &swap2};

    // Ask for a choice
    int choice;
    printf("Which swap algorithm to use? (specify '1' or '2')\n>>> ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("\n");

    // Swap a and b using the right function
    swapTbl[choice - 1](&a, &b);

    // Print the values of a and b
    printf("a is now %d, and b is %d\n\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

First of, if we try to compile and execute it:

```
$ gcc main.c && ./a.out

a is now 1, and b is 2

Which swap algorithm to use? (specify '1' or '2')
>>> 2

swap2 has been called.
a is now 2, and b is 1
```

As myself and others mentioned in answers and in the comments, your functions should all have the same prototype. That means, they must take the same arguments and return the same type. I assumed you actually wanted to make `a` and `b` change, so I opted for `int*, int*` arguments. See @JeremyP 's answer for an explanation of why.